# Scrolltop keeps jumping - Smooth transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am having this to make sure my top header stays at the top.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {                
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 1) {

      $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
  });

.navbar-fixed {
    top: 5;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff !important; 
}
```

The navigation bar is now fixed. But when i approach top, it jumps to the top for few pixels but i am looking for a smooth transition. Can anyone guide how to accomplish this?

Comment: In what browser do you see this? I created this fiddle and it looks fine to me in Chrome and Firefox. https://jsfiddle.net/7095uhfz/

Comment: You must show a minimum of code with the header that uses because in the tests with the code published works well.

Comment: In Chrome, i have a banner image below which contents are displayed

Comment: ok, but what's the original `top` value of the navbar?

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate distance between nav bar and the top of the viewport during scroll to do it:

```js
var navbarOff = $('#nav_bar').offset().top
$(window).scroll(function () {                 
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var distance = scrollTop - navbarOff;
    if (distance >= 0) {
      $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
    if (scrollTop < navbarOff){
      $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
});
```

```css
body{
    margin:0px;
}

.viewport{
    height:200vh;
}

.spacer{
    height:100px;
}

#nav_bar{
    background:black;
    height:20px;
}
.navbar-fixed {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="viewport">
   <div class="spacer">
   </div>
   <div id="nav_bar">
   </div>
</div>
```